# How to disable the notification setting for signer?

Tags: docusignapi, docusignconnect

Suppose If I am the sender and if I send a document to a recipient, then after signing / completion the recipient must not receive any kind of notification . How to implement this ?

Answer (score 0):

Go to the **Settings** part of the web app (top right) and then on the menu in the right select "Email Preferences" and you can change this. Note this change is for the entire account, not for your integration.

[image]